# What conditions need on $n$ and $m$ to $Z_n(G)\leq \gamma_{m+1}(G)$?

Tags: group-theory

What conditions need on $n$ and $m$ to $Z_n(G)\leq \gamma_{m+1}(G)$?

Where $\gamma_{m+1}(G)$ be $m+1$-st term of the lower central series of $G$ and $Z_n(G)$, $n$-st center, be $n$-st term of the upper central series.

Comment: The only conditions that apply in general are the obvious ones $n=0$ or $m=0$ (assuming $Z_0(G)=1$ and $\gamma_1(G)=G$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.